# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables, gulp

Me está dando este error en la consola al haber instalado con npm la librería "datatables".

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined
at Object.o.2 (main.js? [sm]:2408)
at r (main.js? [sm]:1)
at main.js? [sm]:1
at Object.o.16.bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap (main.js? [sm]:44254)
at r (main.js? [sm]:1)
at main.js? [sm]:1
at Object.o.17.../../node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min (main.js? [sm]:44352)
at r (main.js? [sm]:1)
at t (main.js? [sm]:1)
at main.js? [sm]:1
```

Estoy trabajando con gulp y browserify.

> Archivo main.js donde junto todos los js

```
require('./BootstrapInit');
require('../../node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min');
require('./soporte');
```

> Archivo BootstrapInit.js

```
window.jQuery = $ = require('jquery');
require( 'datatables.net-bs' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-autofill-bs' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedheader' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-keytable' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-responsive' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-rowgroup' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-rowreorder' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-scroller' )( window, window.jQuery );
require( 'datatables.net-select' )( window, window.jQuery );
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
```

> Código JavaScript en la página

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mensajestable").dataTable({
        "aoColumns":[
            null,
            null,
            {"sType": "us_date"},
            <CFIF val(rev) IS 4>
                {"sType": "us_date"},
            <CFELSE>
                null,
            </CFIF>
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ],
        'aoColumns':[
            {'sClass':'left','sWidth':'30px'},
            {'sClass':'center','sWidth':'10px'},
            {'sClass':'right','sWidth':'100px'},
            {'sClass':'right','sWidth':'100px'},
            {'sClass':'left'},
            {'sClass':'center','sWidth':'10px'},
            {'sClass':'left','sWidth':'200px'},
            {'sClass':'left','sWidth':'90px'},
            {'sClass':'left','sWidth':'370px'}
        ],
        'order':[
            [0,"desc"],
        ],
        lengthMenu:[
            [10, 25, 50, 200,-1],
            ['10','25','50','200','todas']
        ],
        'pageLength':25,
        'columnDefs':[
            {'targets':1,'searchable':false,'orderable':false},
            {'targets':2,'searchable':false,'orderable':false},
            {'targets':3,'searchable':false,'orderable':false},
            {'targets':5,'searchable':false,'orderable':false},
            {'targets':8,'searchable':false,'orderable':false}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Y no tienes nada de javascript en la página?

Comment: Ya he añadido el script que tengo en la página